# Input data from multiple sources Azure streaming job

Tags: azure, analytics, powerbi, azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-hub

I need to send data from two devices to my Azure IOT hub.
Both of the devices transmit data with different JSON format. The common column between them is TimeStamp.

Now i need to consume and combine these two inputs and output my data into Power BI.
Can anybody suggest any approach or any link to refer to?

Prateek Raina

Comment: This question is too vague at the moment and is likely to be closed. I suggest editing your question and adding a little sample of your data (anonymised if you like), describe the story you would like to tell, and ask specific questions - what exactly you have problems with.

Answer (score 0):

To implement such a scenario you might want to use [Azure Stream Analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/stream-analytics/) to reconcile the 2 different data types. The query language for ASA is SQL like and is pretty straight forward, it shouldn't be too hard to do this considering your data sources are both json.
Note that you can easily setup PowerBI as the output for Stream Analytics as well.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you send it separately. But if you want to achieve with a single datatable, you can join it with Union.